# ZipInputStream - functional approach to unzip files

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have a zip file containing only files and not directories. I want to unzip the file into a directory by using only functional Java.

The code below works as expected and unzips the file into the target folder.

```
public static void unzip(Path source, Path target) throws IOException {

    try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(source.toFile()))) {

        ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();

        while (zipEntry != null) {

            Path targetDirResolved = target.resolve(zipEntry.getName());

            Path normalizePath = targetDirResolved.normalize();
            if (!normalizePath.startsWith(target)) {
                throw new IOException("Bad zip entry: " + zipEntry.getName());
            }

            Files.copy(zis, normalizePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

            zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();

        }
        zis.closeEntry();

    }
}
```

I want to achieve the same functionality as above but use a more functional approach.

My initial thoughts are to transform the while loop into something like `IntStream.range(0, )....` but the number of entries inside the zip file is not known.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to eliminate the while loop is to use `ZipFile`stream:

```
try (ZipFile fs = new ZipFile(source.toFile())) {
    fs.stream()
      .filter(Predicate.not(ZipEntry::isDirectory))
      // etc
      .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

You could also look at ZIP filesystem with `Files.find` to provide a suitable `Stream` of ZIP entries (of level one files) and if required, do additional filtering / map or other conversions on the stream instead of `forEach` as shown here:

```
try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(source)) {
    for (Path root : fs.getRootDirectories()) {
        try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(root, 1, (p,a) -> a.isRegularFile())) {
            stream.forEach(p -> copy(p, Path.of(target.toString(), p.toString())));
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the above still uses normal loops for root directories and `copy` is a separate method to handle `IOException`:

```
private static void copy(Path from, Path to) {
    try {
        Files.copy(from, to, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```